# checkbox for mobile menu issue

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am using a checkbox and label to hide my menu on the mobile viewport, but I am seem to be targeting the wrong element for my :checked property.

this is my HTML markup:

```
<header id="wrapper">
        <label for="toggle">&#9776</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="toggle">
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Meny 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Meny 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Meny 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Meny 4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Meny 5</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>                    
        </header>
```

and this is my targeting css:

```
#toggle{
    display:none;
}

#toggle:checked + #wrapper nav{
    display:block;
}
```

What am I missing out?

-thanks

Comment: It should be `#toggle:checked + nav`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I understood it correct, but is this what you need?

```css
#toggle {
  display: none;
}

#toggle:not(:checked)+nav {
  display: none;
}

#toggle:checked+nav {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<header id="wrapper">
  <label for="toggle">&#9776</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="toggle">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Meny 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Meny 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Meny 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Meny 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Meny 5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: thanks, I can't make my work, I will have to debug it more :)